# Show that there exist an injective homomorphism of dihedral group $D_n$ into $G$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, dihedral-groups

Let:
$$n\gt2 \; \text{and the group} \; (G,⋅)$$
Consider that there existe:

> $a,b∈G$ such that $a^n=b^2=1_G$ and $b⋅a=a^{−1}⋅b$
>
> > and $n$ is the smallest $n≥1$,  such that $a^n=1_G$.
> >
> > > **Show that there exist an injective homomorphism of dihedral group $D_n$ into $G$.**

I know that the dihedral group $D_n$ has the same properties:

$a,b∈G$ such that $a^n=b^2=1_G$ and $b⋅a=a^{−1}⋅b$ as the group $(G,⋅)$.

> **How to find an injective homomorphism,**
>   *that would prove the existence of a monomorphism of dihedral group $D_n$ into $G$?*

Does someone could help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let:
 $$D_n=\langle x,y | x^n, y^2, (xy)^2 \rangle$$

We can define a homomorphism by giving the action on its generators,
so consider the homomorphism:
$$\phi: D_n \rightarrow G \; \text{given by} \; x \mapsto a, \; y \mapsto b$$

> **What can you say about $\phi$?**

Comment: I haven't seen the generator concept yet. Is it possible to write with a somewhat simpler notation?

Comment: Are you happy with my notation for $D_n$ and that every element can be written as a product of $x$ and $y$?

Comment: No, I'm not happy with your notation for $D_n$

Comment: Ok how do you define $D_n$ then?

Comment: Like this : $D_n = \{ \begin{array}{lc} \left(\begin{matrix}
                    \cos2\pi k / n & -\sin2\pi k / n\\
                    \sin2\pi k / n& \cos2\pi k / n
                    \end{matrix}\right) \\\end{array}, k \in \mathbb{Z} \} \cup \{\begin{array}{lc} \left(\begin{matrix}
                    \cos2\pi k / n & \sin2\pi n \\
                    \sin2\pi n / 4& -\cos2\pi k/n  \\
                   \end{matrix}\right) \\\end{array}, k \in \mathbb{Z} \}$, the set of rotations and reflections

Comment: Ok define $\phi$ as $\begin{pmatrix} cos 2\pi k/n & -sin 2\pi k/n \\ sin 2\pi k/n & cos 2\pi k/n \end{pmatrix}$ $\mapsto a^k$ and $\begin{pmatrix} cos 2\pi k/n & -sin 2\pi n \\ sin 2\pi n/4 & -cos 2\pi k/n \end{pmatrix}$ $\mapsto a^kb$. You need to show this is injective and a homomorphism.

Comment: It is only injective if we limit $k \in \{0,1,\dots,n-1\}$ (or some other transversal of $\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$).

Comment: @DavidWheeler actually no since $k=0$ and $k=n$ actually give the *same* element and not just the same iamge. OP may need to justify that this is a finite set of distinct elements though.